VS Code - поставщики систем управления версий не зарегистрированы
Стоит Windows 10 Pro на ней VS Code с ней работаю в WSL2.
Пропала регистрация поставщиков систем управления версиями.
Не знаю, как я нашаманил (может какое лишнее расширение поставил), но гита нет. Точнее он не показывает папку .git и это наверное логично т.к.


как вернуть поставщиков? :)
Версия: 1.92.0 (system setup)
Фиксация: b1c0a14de1414fcdaa400695b4db1c0799bc3124
Дата: 2024-07-31T23:26:45.634Z
Electron: 30.1.2
ElectronBuildId: 9870757
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.14.0
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
ОС: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045


¿git какой версии установлен?

git version 2.34.1
еще 2 дня назад все работало, версии не переставлял. Если в терминале сам  git работает.

добавлю, если закрыть рабочую область, закрыть программу и открыть, от все также как на первом скрине - поставщики систем управления версий не зарегистрированы

ИМХО дело не в git а в VS Code

похоже вопрос решился см. было отключено расширение Git. Вопрос решен.
